# How to store data in Graphite with retention of 100ms?

Tags: graphite, graphite-carbon, whisper

I am using graphite to display our application stats.

**storage-schemas.conf**

```
[stats]
pattern = ^stats\.
retentions = 1s:1h,1m:1d,1h:100d
```

**storage-aggregation.conf**

```
[stats]
pattern = ^stats.*
xFilesFactor = 0
aggregationMethod = sum
```

Per second I am sending data 100 times.

With the above configuration, it is taking only one value every second.

I want to sum all the 100 values sent in a second and store them at that second.

How can I aggregate this data in graphite?

I tried to set retention to 0.01s:1h  but its not working.

Is there any way to store data every 100 ms?

I searched everywhere but didn't find a proper solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper solution will be using Graphite together with StatsD. StatsD aggregates your irregular / high resolution data and sending to Graphite regularly.

Keep in mind, you have to change your client side to send data to statsd instead of graphite.

You can find more information from here: https://github.com/statsd/statsd

If you have high number of metrics I recommend using C version of it https://github.com/statsite/statsite